# Resetting Bean when using Ajax events in PrimeFaces

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a dialog, which contains checkbox and one input field. When this checkbox is checked, input should be disabled. Checkbox value is stored in Bean and input value is one of the selected object values.

This dialog pops up, when user clicks on a link on the list. Dialog's inputs are being populated with values from model.

I have also two buttons: save and cancel. On save, depending on checkbox value, I'm doing different stuff with the model and updating it. On cancel I want to do nothing.

The problem is: when there are ajax events connected with checkbox, value in Bean is automatically updated. So after clicking cancel and reopening the dialog, I got last state, but I want initial state.

Here is the code:

List

```
<h:form id="termPanelForm">

    <p:dataTable id="termPanelTable"
        value="#{termRightPanelController.terms}" var="term" emptyMessage="">

        <p:column>
            <p:commandLink value="#{term.subject}"
                action="#{termRightPanelController.setTerm(term)}"
                oncomplete="termRealizeDlg.show();"
                update=":termRealizeForm:termRealizeDialog" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column width="50">
            <h:outputText value="#{term.dateRealization}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yy HH:mm" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

Dialog

```
<h:form id="termRealizeForm">
    <p:dialog id="termRealizeDialog" widgetVar="termRealizeDlg"
        modal="true" resizable="false" closeOnEscape="true"
        header="#{termRightPanelController.selectedTerm.subject}">

        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true"></p:messages>

        <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="border-none">

            <p:outputLabel for="realized" value="#{i18n['Term.MarkRealized']}" />
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="realized"
                value="#{termRightPanelController.termRealized}">
                <p:ajax process="@this" update="dateRealization" />
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

            <p:outputLabel for="dateRealization"
                value="#{i18n['Term.ChangeDateRealization']}" />
            <p:inputText id="dateRealization"
                value="#{termRightPanelController.selectedTerm.dateRealization}"
                pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
                disabled="#{termRightPanelController.termRealized}" >
            </p:inputText>

        </p:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="buttons-group">
            <p:commandButton value="#{i18n['Common.Save']}"
                oncomplete="hideDialogWhenValid(termRealizeDlg, xhr, status, args);"
                action="#{termRightPanelController.editTerm()}"
                update=":termPanelForm:termPanelTable" icon="ui-icon-check"></p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton onclick="termRealizeDlg.hide();"
                value="#{i18n['Common.cancel']}" 
                icon="ui-icon-cancel" update=":termRealizeForm:termRealizeDialog">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>

    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Bean

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TermRightPanelController extends MainController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6283828584670862366L;

    private TermServiceLocal termService = ServiceLocator.locateService(
            TermService.class, TermServiceLocal.class);

    private List<Term> terms;

    private Term selectedTerm;

    private boolean termRealized;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        loadTerms();
    }

    public void loadTerms() {
        terms = termService.getTermsNotRealized(getLoggedUser().getId());
    }

    public String expiredTerm(Term term) {
        long time = new Date().getTime();
        if (term.getDateRealization().getTime() > time) {
            return "";
        }

        return "expired";
    }

    public void editTerm() {
        if (termRealized) {
            selectedTerm.setDateRead(new Date());
        } else {
            selectedTerm.setDateRead(null);
        }
        termService.merge(selectedTerm);
        loadTerms();
    }

    public void setTerm(Term term) {
        this.selectedTerm = term;
    }

    public List<Term> getTerms() {
        return terms;
    }

    public void setTerms(List<Term> terms) {
        this.terms = terms;
    }

    public Term getSelectedTerm() {
        return selectedTerm;
    }

    public void setSelectedTerm(Term selectedTerm) {
        this.selectedTerm = selectedTerm;
    }

    public boolean isTermRealized() {
        return termRealized;
    }

    public void setTermRealized(boolean termRealized) {
        this.termRealized = termRealized;
    }

    @Override
    public Class getModelClass() {
        return this.getClass();
    }
}
```

In this particular scenario, I can always set `termRealized` to false when I click cancel, but in other scenarios I have values loaded from model. So after reopening dialog I want to have the same values as in model, not stored by Bean.

We have discussed some possible solutions in team, but for us, all seem to be nasty:

1. We could clone `selectedTerm` on select and reload it from clone on cancel. It is nasty, because we need to implement clonable interface on each element we want to edit.
2. We could write custom JavaScript to handle disabled events and other. But we want to avoid using JS, because this is not clean solution.
3. We could reload `selectedTerm` from model on cancel and then replace it on `terms` list. But why are we forced to get something from DB again?
4. We could reload whole `terms` list. This is even worse than 3rd solution.

We have also tried built-in reset options (resetInput tags and other), but no use. Is there any elegant way to fix this or maybe one of our suggestions is correct?

Comment: Maybe you could use a RequestScoped bean for holding the properties that should be reset on each dialog open? And use a PostConstruct interceptor for resetting them in a proper way.

Comment: With RequestScoped bean, `dateRealization` gets cleared, when checking checkbox. Also, it can have unexpected behaviour for us (we probably have this problem on more than two dialogs). But Your answer can me modified to our first solution: hold all properties than should be reset (in clone object) and reset them after clicking cancel (instead of PostConstruct).

Comment: You can use 2 beans with 2 different scopes, and inject the request scoped into the view scoped by means of ManagedProperty annotation.

Comment: @MarcinBigoraj - I don't see a way to avoid temporarily storing the value somewhere until the user clicks OK. The question is now *where* to store the value. My suggestion would be use the JSF `flashScope` to hold `selectedTerm` until the user confirms the selection. Then you update the model

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the following way.

Create a [copy constructor](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=effective%2Bjava%2Bclone&source=bl&ots=yXGhLnv4O4&sig=zvEip5tp5KGgwqO1sCWgtGyJ1Ns&hl=en&ei=CYANSqygK8jktgfM-JGcCA&sa=X&oi=book%5Fresult&ct=result&resnum=3#PPA54,M1) for the Term:

```
public class Term {
  private String dummy;

  public Term() {

  }
  //copy constructor
  public Term(Term another) {
     this.dummy = another.dummy; // and set the rest of the values  
   }
}
```

and the button inside dataTable calls the select method.

```
<p:commandLink value="#{term.subject}"
            action="#{termRightPanelController.selectTerm(term)}"
            oncomplete="termRealizeDlg.show();"
            update=":termRealizeForm:termRealizeDialog" />
```

*selectTerm(Term term)*

```
public void selectTerm(Term term) { 
  selectedTerm = new Term(term);
}
```

*dialog onHide*

```
 <p:dialog id="termRealizeDialog" widgetVar="termRealizeDlg"
    modal="true" resizable="false" closeOnEscape="true"
    header="#{termRightPanelController.selectedTerm.subject}" 
    onHide="restDialog()">
```

*restDialog()* remoteCommand

```
<p:remoteCommand name="restDialog"
actionListener="#{termRightPanelController.restDialogValues()}" />
```

*restDialogValues()*

```
public void restDialogValues() {
  setTermRealized(false);
}
```

*save button*

```
<p:commandButton value="#{i18n['Common.Save']}"
   action="#{termRightPanelController.editTerm()}" />
```

*editTerm()*

```
public void editTerm() {
   ....
   terms.remove(selectedTerm);//assuming equals and hashcode works on ID
   terms.add(selectedTerm);
   // Or loop over the terms and find your selectedTerm by id
   // if the equals and hashcode are not implemented on the ID, 
   //then remove it and add the new one
   ....
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution is just cloning, where clone method is realized by second constructor. The biggest disadvantage of this approach is in copying properties one by one. And this gets multiplied by number of objects we are editing by dialogs.

Comment: Well it is like cloning, but for me this is the "only" solution to avoid dealing with the database.
I mean you have listed out 4 possible solutions, and the first one is the clone, well cloning is not practical as copy constructor is.